# Difference in hypothesis testing using p-value and confidence interval

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, p-value, proportion, z-test

I have a simple problem

> The sample population is 384 people and $12$% of it have a disease. The hypothesis is that $5$% of the real population have a disease. So, $H_0: \mu = 0.05$ and $H_a: \mu \neq 0.05$

First I calculate the Z-statistic.
$$
z = \frac{\hat{p}-p}{\sqrt{p*(1-p)/384}} = \frac{0.12-0.05}{\sqrt{0.05*(1-0.05)/384}} = 6.3
$$

Using the p-value to test the hypothesis (I used R `2*(1-pnorm(6.3))`):
$$
2*Φ(-|6.3|)= 2.976457e^{-10}
$$
which is less than 0.05 level of significance, thus, reject the Null.

Using the confidence interval with 0.05 significance level:

$$
\hat{p} \pm z*\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/384} = 0.12 \pm 6.3*\sqrt{0.12(1-0.12)/384}
\\ \mbox{I get the following} \\
0.0155 < 0.05 <0.224
$$

So according to the confidence interval I cannot reject the Null. Is it I doing something wrong or is it sometimes the case that there is a disagreement between the two approaches? Granted there are cases in which the the CI and the p-value disagree which one should I go with? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relation between confidence interval and testing statistical hypothesis for t-test](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18215/relation-between-confidence-interval-and-testing-statistical-hypothesis-for-t-te)

Comment: This is a different issue than the linked thread. There is a confusion here about what value to use for z in the confidence interval.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With large $N$, your test statistic will be distributed as a normal.  Thus, we can refer to your test statistic as "$z$", and we can also use "$z$" to refer to the asymptotic sampling distribution.  However, these are not the same $z$'s.  When you form your $1-\alpha\%$ confidence interval, you need to multiply the standard error by $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ to get the right increment.  You then add (subtract) the product from your observed percentage to get the confidence limits.  For example, if you wanted a $95\%$ confidence interval, you would multiply your standard error by $z_{.975} = 1.96$.  If you use this value, your confidence interval is:
\begin{align}
\hat{p} \pm z_{1-\alpha/2}\times \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{N}} &= 0.12 \pm 1.96\times\sqrt{\frac{0.12(1-0.12)}{384}}  \\[10pt]
&= 0.0872  < 0.12 < 0.15
\end{align}
which agrees with your hypothesis test.

Comment: I just realized you welcomed me to this website  three years ago when I asked my first question. Good to see you still active.

Comment: You're welcome, @Koba. What question are you referring to?

Comment: [This one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43963) presumably.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have rep to comment, but I see some flaws in that problem.
First, 6.3 sigmas are way more than 0.95 C.L. Just apply quickly Chebyshev theorem.
A confidence level says that "in N experiments, if at least 1 - p experiments you get the null hypothesis you can't reject it".

Then, a binomial distribution isn't symmetrical,but there are enough observations so it seems like symmetrical if you do an histogram.

Answer (score 2):

Just to grasp the concept, I've been working on a couple of plots to illustrate why the $z$ statistic calculates the *standard error* expected around the *population* or *theoretical* proportion (from the perspective of the *Null* hypothesis so to speak), and then figures out how many of these *standard errors* fit into the distance from the theoretical population proportion to the sample proportion - in this case ~$\small6$ - as shown on this plot with six arrow separating the population from the sample proportions:

[image]

And why, on the other hand the *confidence interval* does the same thing, but from the perspective of the possible *alternative hypothesis*, or in other words, from the sample mean: it is the proportion found in the sample that is used to calculate the *standard error*. This latter calculation is plotted with the confidence interval shown as diverging arrows away from the sample proportion, and covering two *standard errors* on either side (the *confidence interval*):

[image]

In either case the conclusion is the same: rejecting $H_o$ in favor of $H_a: \,\mu \neq0.05$.

[Code for illustrations here.](https://github.com/RInterested/SIMULATIONS_and_PROOFS/blob/master/Z-test%20Proportions%20v%20Confidence%20Intervals)

Comment: The figures are good, but I feel that they don't even start to explain the OP's confusion. The core confusion is that even though sample proportion is 6 standard errors away from 0.5, the 95% confidence interval is not sample proportion plus minus 6 standard errors; it's only plus minus 2 standard errors. I feel like your second figure could show this explicitly.

Comment: @amoeba Thank you for looking into it. If you have the time and inclination to give me concrete changes or additions you would consider, I will definitely reflect on them.

Comment: Well, you show 6 SEs as 6 little arrows on your figure 1, so I thought you could show in your figure 2 that the width of the conf interval is given by only 2 of these little arrows. And then comment (in words) on this difference.

Comment: @amoeba Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to change it including your tips.

Comment: Good job! You have my +1.